# Papercrop is not saving cropped image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, paperclip, carrierwave

I have installed papercrop 0.3 and am using paperclip version 4.3.1 37589f9.

I have the following code in my cropping view:

```
 <%= form_for @image, url: wizard_path, method: :put, html:{ class: "padding #{"processed" if @event.errors.present?}" } do |f| %>
      <%= f.cropbox :photo, :width => 500 %>
       <%= f.crop_preview :photo, :width => 150 %>
      <%= f.submit "Save", , :id=>"commit" %>
 <% end %>
```

The image and preview render correctly. I press the submit button and the following is the output in my server console:

```
Started PUT "/events/90/activity_setup/activity_image_crop" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-29 03:19:16 -0500
Processing by ActivitySetupController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9P3TTupYZPpbudEtcy2NUi7vQM98FViFslQGWteffRPz8nQ/SYI0JIhclFH4C6Zi0SQdiiBzJEoBhLEaKxhzdA==", "event_image"=>{"photo_original_w"=>"655", "photo_original_h"=>"435", "photo_box_w"=>"500", "photo_aspect"=>"1.0", "photo_crop_x"=>"381", "photo_crop_y"=>"124", "photo_crop_w"=>"250", "photo_crop_h"=>"250"}, "commit"=>"", "event_id"=>"90", "id"=>"activity_image_crop"}
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 90]]
step is:activity_image_crop
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "event_categories" WHERE "event_categories"."event_id" = $1  [["event_id", 90]]
  Schedule Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE "schedules"."event_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["event_id", 90]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "ticket_types" WHERE "ticket_types"."event_id" = $1  [["event_id", 90]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "event_images" WHERE "event_images"."event_id" = $1  [["event_id", 90]]
  EventImage Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "event_images".* FROM "event_images" WHERE "event_images"."event_id" = $1  ORDER BY "event_images"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["event_id", 90]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-uttb90.jpeg'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; convert '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]' -crop 250x250+381+124 -auto-orient -resize "x100" +repage -quality 100 '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/8dc9c06ba7fa16c1011aed269772a9cf20160229-53505-ehwzjg'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; convert '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]' -crop 250x250+381+124 -auto-orient -resize "450x300!" -quality 100 '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/8dc9c06ba7fa16c1011aed269772a9cf20160229-53505-pfkfle'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; convert '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]' -crop 250x250+381+124 -auto-orient -resize "600x400!" -quality 100 '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/8dc9c06ba7fa16c1011aed269772a9cf20160229-53505-1q3w5pu'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; convert '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/0d0871f0806eae32d30983b62252da5020160229-53505-1gxacyq.jpeg[0]' -crop 250x250+381+124 -auto-orient -resize "750x300!" -quality 100 '/var/folders/ph/fy4ch9s11ssgdrc_dd8ltr040000gn/T/8dc9c06ba7fa16c1011aed269772a9cf20160229-53505-1g591aq'
[paperclip] deleting /Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/clazzoo_main/public/system/event_images/photos/000/000/096/original/929.jpeg
[paperclip] deleting /Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/clazzoo_main/public/system/event_images/photos/000/000/096/thumb/929.jpeg
[paperclip] deleting /Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/clazzoo_main/public/system/event_images/photos/000/000/096/medium/929.jpeg
[paperclip] deleting /Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/clazzoo_main/public/system/event_images/photos/000/000/096/large/929.jpeg
[paperclip] deleting /Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/Personal/clazzoo_main/public/system/event_images/photos/000/000/096/desktop/929.jpeg
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
```

If you look closely, my crop_x of 381 and crop_y 124 appear to be in console commands, which means things are going well.....I can see the command : `-crop 250x250+381+124` a number of times.

However, when I then render my image using :

```
<%= image_tag @event.event_images.first.photo.url %> I get the same unchanged image. Do I need to pass some kind of parameter to url to show my cropped file?!
```

My model where the image is stored is here:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: event_images
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  caption            :string
#  event_id           :integer
#  created_at         :datetime         not null
#  updated_at         :datetime         not null
#  photo_file_name    :string
#  photo_content_type :string
#  photo_file_size    :integer
#  photo_updated_at   :datetime
#  canned_image_id    :string
#

class EventImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTS

  has_attached_file :photo, PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTS
  crop_attached_file :photo

  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]
  validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, :attributes => :photo, :less_than => 3.megabytes

  belongs_to :event

   def photo_url(size=nil)
    if(canned_image_id)then
      path = ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path("event_create/activity_image/choice-"+canned_image_id+".png")
      path = path.sub! '/assets/', ''
      return path
    else
      if(size)then
        return photo.url(size)
      else
        return photo.url()
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the controller code for updating the instance of this model is (which is inside the update method :

```
image = @event.event_images.first
 image.update_attributes(image_params)
```

My PAPER_CLIP_STORAGE_OPTS are:

```
PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTS = {
     :styles => { :thumb => '100x100!#', :medium => '450x300!>', :large => '600x400!>', :desktop => '750x300!>'},
     :convert_options => { :all => '-quality 100' },
     :processor       => [ :cropper,:papercrop ],
     :default_url => 'business.jpg'
   }
```

I tried removing :cropper from the processor array incase that might have been conflicting, but it made no difference.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple app to reproduce your problem: https://github.com/universal/papercropTest

From that example app, the papercrop gem seems to only crop the variations defined in styles, but leaves the original file untouched. So i guess the code you have already works, just slightly different than you expected.

So the thumb, medium and large variations should be correctly cropped, and the original stays unchanged. This makes sense imho, but might just be counterintuitive. :-)